# Configure base URL depending on environment

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

Suppose we have Angular 4+ app that needs to be located in different relative root URLs on different environments, i.e.:

- `http://localhost:4200/index.html` for development
- `http://prod.server.com/angular-app/index.html` for production

Most likely, we'd want to have that option in our `environment.x.ts` files:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    appRoot: "/"
};

export const environment = {
    production: true,
    appRoot: "/angular-app/"
};
```

How can we configure Angular build/runtime infrastructure to automatically adjust the app depending on this option in `environment.x.ts` files?

**UPDATE:**
Since I'm using the Angular CLI toolchain indirectly via Visual Studio build/publish system ([template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate)), it'd be nice to have a solution based completely on Angular CLI + `*.json`/`*.ts`/`*.js` files. This way it would be suitable for any build system where Angular CLI could be used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using the Angular CLI you can do:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myUrl/
```

OR

```
ng build --prod --bh /myUrl/
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using  Angular CLI, but via Visual Studio build/publish system([VS template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate)). Do you know how to control those cmd line params depending on Debug\Release configuration of VS build?

Comment: Or what seems to be more build toolchain agnostic, is there a way to control Angular CLI's`--base-href` via some `.json` config file that we could put in project?

Comment: No, I don't know how to work these into a VS build. I didn't think the two (Visual Studio and the CLI) played very well together yet ... but was hoping to see some improvements over time.

Comment: Well, the CLI has environment files for configuration types of things ... but I don't know that the VS build will pick up those either? (Ah, and I see that was part of your question as well.)

Comment: I assume you've seen this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, thank you! But still it seems the only way to change the base URL is via cmd line args.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative to the option described in [@DeborahK answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45970803/3345644) could be to add build configurations to `package.json` and setup your IDE to specify the desired build configuration depending on environment it's building for.

Here is a snippet from `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:Debug": "ng build --dev --base-href /",
    "build:Release": "ng build --prod --base-href /angular-app/",
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

And here is a snippet of `.csproj` file to give you an idea of how it could be integrated with Visual Studio (credits to @Andrey_Fomin in this [discussion](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyFomin.AngularCLIProjectTemplate#qna)):

```
  <Target Name="NgBuildAndAddToPublishOutput" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <Exec Command="npm run | findstr &quot;build:$(Configuration)&quot;" ConsoleToMSBuild="true" IgnoreExitCode="true" EchoOff="true" WorkingDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)">
      <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="NpmScriptName" />
    </Exec>
    <Exec Condition=" '$(NpmScriptName)'=='build:$(Configuration)' " Command="npm run $(NpmScriptName)" />
    <Exec Condition=" '$(NpmScriptName)'!='build:$(Configuration)' " Command="npm run build" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATED:
Carefully follow these steps and you are good to go :)
----------------------------------------------------------
1. Create 4 files in environment folder: (2 might there by default)
example: 
environment.ts, environment.prod.ts,environment.test1.ts,environment.test2.ts

2. Use this common code for every file with slight change:

    export const environment = {
      production: true, //production is true for environment.prod.ts file
                        //for other test production is false
      apiUrl: ''        //base_url of each environment
    };

3. Maintain a constant file where you will write all base urls.
code sample of constant.ts:

    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    let url = environment.apiUrl;
    export const AppConstant = Object.freeze({
        BASE_API_URL: url,
    }

4. import this constant in your service or component class wherever your calling back-end. 

5. In angular-cli.json: 


    "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
          "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
            "test1": "environments/environment.test1.ts",
            "test2": "environments/environment.test2.ts"
          }

6.

    ng build --env=prod
    ng build --env=dev / ng build
     ng build --env=test1
     ng build --env=test2

7. if aot is creating problem. you can use :  ng build --env=prod --no-aot

8. TO make things simple: 

you can additonally add new build commands: 
 "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --env=local --no-aot",
    "start:qa": "ng serve --env=dev --no-aot",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod --env=prod --no-aot --output-hashing=all",
    "build:dev": "ng build --prod --env=dev --no-aot --output-hashing=all",
    "build:local": "ng build --env=local"
  }
When you run,command is  ==> npm run start OR npm run start:qa 
OR==> npm run build:local or npm run build:dev, etc.

9. Hashing will solve caching isuue.

Hope it solves your problem. It works for me.
```

Comment: This actually does not solve Alexander's problem but it helped me with the issue of setting up my services to reference base urls defined in the environment files so will up-vote you.

Comment: up voting for the same reason @Ronald91 mentioned. Thanks for the deep explanation on this.

Answer (score 5):

In angular 6 we can do it in better way, by using environment.x.ts (x means it might be production/development/configuration etc files).

suppose if its dev mode file name(environment.dev.ts)

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    appRoot: "/" or appRoot: "http://somerestapi"
};
```

suppose if its in production mode file name(environment.prod.ts)

```
   export const environment = {
        production: true,
        appRoot: "/" or appRoot: "http://somerestapi"
    };
```

and same appRoot can be used in all services as in below 
service.ts file.

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

 appRoot = environment.appRoot;

    emplLoginCheckUrl = this.appRoot + "/checkValidUser";

      validateUserDetails(employeeDetails): Observable<any> {
            console.log(this.appRoot );
            return this._httpClinet.post(this.emplLoginCheckUrl, employeeDetails);
        }
```

after this we have one more job to do, its open your angular.json file

apply below changes to "dev": mode

```
"dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
```

and apply below changes to "production": mode

```
 "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
```

but you have to choose which one is needed to run the application, like if you want to run in dev mode use below command it will automatically apply appRoot(URL) for all aservices where you called.

ng build --configuration=dev (for development mode).
ng build --configuration=production (for production mode).