# In multi container setup, failing to call service from another container while using Docker-Compose

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose with multi container setup. I have an angular app, deployed on nginx and exposed to port 80. On second container, I am hosting .note core API, this service is returning a string.

In angular, I am calling  URL http://localhost/api/values

Take a look at my attached docker compose.yml file. With my current set-up, when I hit "http://localhost:81" in my local browser, I get the desired result.

But, in Angular app (http://localhost/api/values) , rather than using "localhost", I wanted to use "webapi"(http://webapi/api/values), I tried all sorts of options but I am not getting desired output. So far, I tried using hostname, container_name, aliases, etc

I would appreciate if you can point out my mistake here and help me to get desire output. Also, I would appreciate if you can suggest best option in case we run multiple instances on .net service.

Once this issues is solved, I am planning to deploy it on Azure, would I be needing any additional settings/configurations?

Here is my yml file

Thanks in advance.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: hello
    container_name: web
    hostname: web
    image: jayforu/hello
    networks:
      backend:
         #aliases: 
          #  - web
      #   ipv4_address: 172.16.238.01

    ports:
      - 81:80
  webapi:
    build: HelloApi
    container_name: webapi
    hostname: webapi
    image: jayforu/helloapi
    networks:
      backend:
         #aliases: 
          #  - webapi
        #ipv4_address: 172.16.238.02
    ports:
      - 80:80
networks:
  backend:
   # ipam:
      driver: bridge
    #  config:
     #   - subnet: "172.16.238.0/24"
```

Comment: this is actually not docker issue, its something related to the Angular and its configuration, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970744/configure-base-url-depending-on-environment

Comment: Have you tried calling `http://webapi:80/api/values`?

Comment: on another note you still can use your URL as localhost, the exact issue here is the port, if you use port `81` it should work for you, since you published port `81`

Comment: with locahost it works on 81, when I change localhost to webapi or webapi:80, it fails. And I doubt if it's Angular issue. I am just calling service which reside on another container.

Comment: @mamounothman I have changed configuration and I have added my code on public git repo, would you please find some time to take a look at it?  I created logs folder to show you network info and my steps for building project. API URL is getting consumed in file hello-world.service.ts.  https://github.com/jayrajvcybage/dockercompose.git I would highly appreciate if you can rectify my mistake, if any

Comment: @JPM I'm having a look at the setup now, the thing is I'm don't have experience in .netcore, this is my first encounter, but its ok, so does HelloApi define api end-point? and what ports should this api run on, I was checking and noticed there is 80, and 443 exposed in HelloApi/Dockerfile, if I'm, to run this Docker alone and I want to access the api point how can I do it, if I know I will be able to fix the issue here.

Comment: @mamounothman Thanks a lot! If you just want to build and run .net project then  1. docker build --rm -f "Dockerfile" -t helloapi2:latest "."  2. Run it on 81 for time being docker run --rm -it -p 81:80/tcp helloapi2:latest 3. API returns two values ; http://localhost:81/api/values

Comment: @mamounothman I was also making a rookie mistake while deploying this project on Azure and using localhost on Angular side to make it work, I went back to localhost as webapi was not getting discovered. It wont get as on Azure localhost wont matter, I would have to use IP, I guess?

Comment: @JPM, I was able to get values from the api after you provided the instruction to build and run the image here: https://imgur.com/YqKS1lG, I will post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, here is what you have to do to make it work

Build images manually and specify the locally built images in docker-compose (I think this is not required since you build the images inside docker-compose)

```
# My docker compose installation doesn't support 3.7.
version: '3.6'

services:
  web:
    image: hello:latest
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
        - 80:80
  webapi:
    image: helloapi2:latest
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - 81:80
networks:
  backend:
      driver: bridge
```

I changed the http.get method `url` and `port` in hello-worl.service.ts to whatever your host is, in my case I'm using virtual machine so my containers are deployed on http://192.168.99.100 and listening on port 81 as specified in docker-compose for `webapi` service, in your case if its localhost then change it to `http://localhost:81`

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HelloWorldService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }
    messages: string[];
    executeHelloWorldService(): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.http.get<string[]>('http://http://192.168.99.100:81/api/values').pipe(
        map((data: string[]) => {
          this.messages = data;
          return true;
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely works, but, this doesnt work , http://webapi:80/api/values when webapi is a host/hostname on Docker's bridge. As call is going from JS, I believe, it can find locahost but not webapi.

Comment: @JPM I think I misunderstood your question, the thing for Angular app is to have the API URL dynamically stored in settings file and use it based on environment (production, local, staing, testing).