# For which reason this Angular Service is not working?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an Angular app with controller. I can successfully use the controller (with Postman, see screenshot below).

At the fronted I implemented a new component including service to show the data from controller (see code below). The service is not working. No data are shown at the application.

I made a breakpoint in `feedback.service.ts`/`getFeedbacks()` and in `feedback.component.ts`/`ngOnInit()`. Both are reached.

I mad a *breakpoint* at my *controller* and this one is *never reached* (except using postman).

Why doesn't the data from the controller reach the GUI?

[image]

feedback.component.html:

```html
<div style="margin: 35px;">
   <h1>Feedback List:</h1>
   <div *ngFor="let feedback of feedbacks">
       {{feedback.comment}}
   </div>
 
   <h2>Count: {{feedbacks.length}}</h2>
</div>
```

feedback.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Feedback } from './feedback';
import { FeedbackService } from './feedback.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-feedback',
  templateUrl: './feedback.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./feedback.component.css']
})
export class FeedbackComponent implements OnInit {
  feedbacks: Feedback[] = [];
    objects: any;

  constructor(private feedbackService: FeedbackService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.feedbackService
      .getFeedbacks()
      .subscribe(feedbacks => this.feedbacks = feedbacks);
  }
}
```

feedback.service.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Feedback } from './feedback';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FeedbackService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFeedbacks(): Observable<Feedback[]> {
    let result: Observable<Feedback[]>;
    result = this.http.get<Feedback[]>('/feedback');
    return result;
  }
}
```

feedback.ts:

```
export interface Feedback {
    id:      number;
    comment: string;
    userId:  number;
}
```

app.modules.ts:

```
// other imports ...
import { FeedbackComponent } from './feedback/feedback.component';
import { FeedbackService } from './feedback/feedback.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    FeedbackComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: FeedbackComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [FeedbackService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Screenshot from browser:
[image]

Comment: Haven't written angular in a long time but shouldn't the url used for the "result = this.http.get<Feedback[]>('/feedback');" be the full length url instead of only /feedback? Or do you set the base url somewhere else and only need to add the last extension?

Comment: What does the browser's network tab say?

Comment: Could you provide info from your browsers development toold -> console and network tab. Is your Angular app set up on same port as your backend? It might be CORS related problem.

Comment: @Codeaur I tried with hard coded path 'https://localhost:44477/feedback'. It'n not working too.

Comment: @FrankMehlhop What do you get in the console? are there any errors?

Comment: Using the development tool at chrome I see that it is calling https://localhost:44477/feedback, but using postman I reach the controller using http://localhost:5235/feedback.
The 5235 I find at launchSetting.json. So it is a IP mismatch. 
What is a good way to sort that out?

Comment: May be the problem is that I use postman with http and on the browser is used https with different IP.

Comment: It's because you are using a relative url - `/feedback` - instead of the full url to the API - `localhost:5235/feedback`. The API and your angular app are not running on the same port so you can't use relative urls to point to the API.

Comment: Hard coded 44477 or 5235 I get the message: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:5235/feedback' from origin 'https://localhost:44477' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: What technology are you using for the API? The answer on how to configure CORs will depend on the technology you are using.

Comment: @daddygames Using Visual Studio, .Net 6, Angular 12, chrome.

Comment: Is this solution relevant to your API? => [Enable cross-origin requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors)

Answer (score 0):

Configure so that Angular hits the correct url andport `localhost:5235/feedback`. Using developer tools and inspecting network tab you can find your GET request and have look if it's heading to the right direction. Easies way would be to use Angular's enviourment files and change the baseUrl.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532683/15439733

Then after that make sure CORS is enabled on your backend so Angular from another url `localhost:44477` can access that endpoint.

https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-proxy-configuration-to-handle-cors-issue/

Comment: The fix for the CORS-issue is not working because the route is always the same. When I use the same route at the proxy.config.json a second time than it is not accepted because it's a doubling.

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts change this.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.feedbackService
      .getFeedbacks()
      .subscribe(feedbacks => {
          this.feedbacks.push(...feedbacks);
    })
}
```

Change this in your service.ts

```
getFeedbacks(): Observable<Feedback[]> {
    return this.http.get<Feedback[]>('http://localhost:444477/feedback');
}
```

let me know if it worked

Comment: Vincente: It's not working.

Comment: I think you have a problem with the path. Read again my answer, I added a new code

Answer (score 0):

I changed the path to https://localhost:7235/feedback
and now the breakpoint at the controller is reached.

launchSettings.json:

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:51641",
      "sslPort": 44377
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Test3": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7235;http://localhost:5235",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }, // .....
```

package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "test3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "prestart": "node aspnetcore-https",
    "start": "run-script-os",
    "start:windows": "ng serve --port 44477 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key",
    "start:default": "ng serve --port 44477 --ssl --ssl-cert $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.pem --ssl-key $HOME/.aspnet/https/${npm_package_name}.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:ssr": "ng run Test3:server:dev",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },//...
```

app.csproj:

```js
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44477</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup> // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

at the .NET 6 backend, Program.cs
add as first service:

```js
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("TheCodeBuzzPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

then add after app.UseRouting():

```js
app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("TheCodeBuzzPolicy");

});
```